# Angular JS Dynamic Template files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just starting out with AngularJS so apologies if an obvious answer exists. I've been looking all over the web but can't find an answer and don't want to waste time if I'm going down the wrong path.

I want to build template HTML files to load in to my site (header.html/footer.html etc) and control their appearance using Angular. This is working fine using AngularJS directives and static html files:

JS

```
App.directive('load', function() {
    return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: 'E',  
        templateUrl: "inc/header.html"
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div>Static Text</div>
   <load></load>
 </div>
```

load.html

```
<p>Loaded text</p>
```

This works fine, however I need to know is it possible to include AngularJS functionality in to my load.html? If so how can this be achieved? Am I missing something?

for example

load.html

```
<div id="main" ng-app>

    <nav class="{{active}}" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()">
         <a href="#" class="home" ng-click="active='Link 1'">Link 1</a>
    </nav>
    <p ng-show="active">You just clicked <b>{{active}}</b></p>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't need `ng-app` in `load.html`, it will be loaded as part of the current app. Everything else should work as is.

It seems to me, though, that you are duplicating the functionality of [ngInclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude).

Comment: Thanks - removed ng-app in load.html and it works - thanks for the help. We researched ng-include and might test again to see what suits our needs, not really sure which has more benefit over the other